# Writing a dataframe from Python3 into Netezza

Tags: python-3.x, export, netezza

I want to write a dataframe straight from Python into Netezza. Is this even possible? What I am doing right now is exporting to CSV then uploading into Netezza which is quite time consuming...

A dummy dataset is as follows:

```
s1=pd.Series(["Test1"])
s2=pd.Series(["Test2"])
s3=pd.Series(["Test3"])
df=pd.DataFrame([list(s1), list(s2),  list(s3)],  columns =  ["STATUS"])
```

I then connect to Netezza (example):

```
#import libraries
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

engine = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={NetezzaSQL};SERVER=netezzakm01;PORT=5480;DATABASE=SDSNZKM01;UID=KMMTBA;PWD=xxx;")
```

This is as far as I get because anything else I have tried to write with has come nowhere near working...... is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

So far, the best I have been able to do is the following:

1. On the `netezza` side I create a table with the structure I want,

   create table mytablename
   (
   MYDATE DATE,
   MYDISTRIBUTEKEY BIGINT,
   SOMESTRING VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL,
   SOMEINT INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
   SOMEFLOAT FLOAT DEFAULT NULL
   ) distribute on (mydistributekey);
2. my dataframe say `mydf` is such that

   list(mydf.columns)
   == ['MYDATE','MYDISTRIBUTEKEY','SOMESTRING','SOMEINT','SOMEFLOAT']
3. dump the dataframe to disk

   mydf.to_csv('df_on_disk.tab',sep='\t',index=False,header=False)
4. you can now to a BULK load of the file on disk into netezza, from `netezza`.  Note that I connect via a JDBC, with `jaydebeapi`.

   INSERT INTO mytablename SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL 'df_on_disk.tab' USING (DELIM '\t' REMOTESOURCE 'JDBC'); GENERATE STATISTICS ON mytablename;

This is not the exact solution, but you would want to do something like that.